# How to get instagram photos by using flex

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flex4.5

Is there any easy way to get photos of a particular user by using flex web application. I had gone through this [link](http://instagram.com/developer/authentication/#), but it didn't help me a lot.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/instagr-as3/source/browse/trunk/instagrAS3/oauth/OAuth.as

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use StageWebView and listen for its LocationChangeEvent.LOCATION_CHANGE event.

I haven't tried Instagram, but it works for me with Facebook and Google+